# Springboot Mockito : Mocked service method returning null

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, microservices

I'm trying to test my springboot service using mockito but getting null response from my mocked service
The code compiles and also the service runs perfectly but test cases fail as mocked service returns null.

Service class

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(path = "/my-tracker")
    public class MyTrackerController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTrackerController .class); 

    @Autowired
    private TrackerService trackerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/track/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public String getTrackerDetails(@PathVariable("id") String id) 
        {

        String response = trackerservice.track(id);  // <= this is returning null 

        return response;
        }

    }
```

Test Class

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @WebMvcTest(value = MyTrackerController.class)
public class MyTrackerControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private TrackerService trackerService ;

    @Test
    public void getTrackerDetailsTest() throws Exception {

        String response= "MyLocation";


        Mockito.when(
                trackerService.track(
                        Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(response);


        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
                "/my-tracker/track/123").accept(
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        System.out.println(result.getResponse());

        JSONAssert.assertEquals(response, result.getResponse()
                .getContentAsString(), true);
        }
    }
```

Any help / suggestions is highly appreciated.
Springboot version used : 2.3.0.RELEASE.

Blog referred for writing test case : https://www.springboottutorial.com/unit-testing-for-spring-boot-rest-services

p.s. : I'am able to run test cases successfully from the above blog code but my mocked service is returning null. Also no additional jars added apart from spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter- test

Comment: Could be a mismatch in dependencies of your Mockito files in pom.xml. Make sure there are no version conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

One reason I could think about:

As per the RequestMapping of getTrackerDetails, JSON string is expected to be returned as a response (produces = application/json)

Try returning a valid JSON as a response in your test case.

Example:

```
String response = "\"field\":\"value\"";
```

Comment: The "@RestController" takes care of json conversion. We need not do it explicitly. Also my issue is that the mocked bean is returning null object.

Comment: my bad, sorry I misread the question. Can you add a debug point and check if the trackservice is a mock service?